# How to integrate vimeo api to get videos from my vimeo account and show my site

Tags: drupal, video, vimeo

How to integrate vimeo api in my drupal site to get videos from my vimeo account and show my drupal site and run my drupal site when i click to play/pause button of player.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the Vimeo module?

http://drupal.org/project/vimeo